# How would a unguligrade human (similar to a satyr/faun) ride a horse?

Tags: technology, magic, culture, fantasy-races

I am working on creating a fantasy race called the Aemani. As they are part deer they are [unguligrade](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unguligrade) bipeds (like a faun or satyr).

I am in the midst of creating their culture however I don't know how they would ride a horse, or even if they could.
Would I need to consider another form of transport? It is set in a post-modern but medieval style world. Modern-day technology as we know it today (such as cars) is not available to them.

I would like to have my story as scientifically feasible as possible, even though I understand unguligrade bipeds are quite unrealistic to start with.

Comment: Scientific *feasibility* is vastly overrated.  Go for *reasonably plausible* instead.  Your audience won't notice the difference, and your job will be much easier.

Comment: Yo dogg I heard you like hooves, so we matched a satyr rider to your horse, so you can see him mount while he mounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in modern fantasy settings, [an unguligrade biped is depicted either with the ankle higher up than a normal human's ankle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJmQrULRins#t=03m53s), *or* with an [extra joint](http://animal-dream.com/data_images/satyr/satyr21.jpg) as a [reversed knee](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cassandra-palmer-world/images/d/df/Satyr_2.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20150727011048) while still having [an ankle at the hoof area that faces the normal human knee direction](https://previews.123rf.com/images/bokononist/bokononist1507/bokononist150700003/43758091-satyr-with-pitcher-and-horn.jpg) again. So while the leg may be structured somewhat different, those differences ought not affect riding too much. NOTE: If one researches [more classical Greek depictions of satyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyr), the legs are either normal, or fairly normal to a human's, but I believe you are thinking more the later fantastical version.

#### Prior Renditions

Artists have depicted satyrs riding other animals (I did not find an example of a horse, but the last one is pretty close):

**Riding a Goat**

If I read the info right, this is a 19th-20th century sculpture done in the "Manner of Andrea Briosco, called Riccio," who was a 16th century artist (from https://metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/198377?rpp=30&pg=125&rndkey=20150309, accessed 9/30/2018)

[image]

**Riding a Bull**

Figure based on sculpture by Barthélemy Prieur, ca. 16th century (from https://www.mutualart.com/Artwork/A-bronze-group-of-a-young-satyr-riding-a/DAF62B4FA05DC944, accessed 9/30/2018)

[image]

**Riding a Unicorn**

I don't speak or read Russian, it just happens to be the site where the image was found, but Google translates the page (so if the information is accurate) as having the statue itself located in Cambridge, United Kingdom, created in 1905 by Georg Wrba (from [https://www.diary.ru/~yukatan/p195188584.htm](https://www.diary.ru/%7Eyukatan/p195188584.htm), accessed 9/30/2018)

[image]

#### Logically

There are examples of humans [riding backwards](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=579&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=vdSwW_6vJdPa9AOq5qOQBQ&q=riding%20a%20horse%20seated%20backwards&oq=riding%20a%20horse%20seated%20backwards&gs_l=img.3...202103.210134..210282...4.0..0.88.2261.35......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j0i67j0i8i30j0i24j0i30j0i5i30.k3zDnPmNsHk), which would probably be far harder than a satyr-type creature riding forwards, and some even supposedly in combat, such as this 4th century sculpted plate housed in the Iran Bastan Museum, Tehran, Iran (from http://warfare.tk/6-10/Sassanid-Plate-Bastan-1275.htm, accessed 9/30/2018):

[image]

Further, normally such satyr and faun like people are conceived of being able to jump rather well, so it seems that mounting up on a horse might be easier even than for most humans. Though the size of the people may matter (if they are quite a bit smaller than the average human, then they could still sit a horse, [much as a child *can*](https://good-horse.com/health-management/children-learn-ride-horses-ponies/), but might have a harder time controlling it).

### Conclusion

So conceptually, I believe there is no problem with the idea, though working out a few details related to your particular unguligrade biped people's size, anatomy, and skills may or may not need to be attended to.

Comment: sweet images!  would you please ink sources?  I would like to know more about the unicorn and your medal of a Parthian is better than anything I found when I looked.

Comment: @Willk I added image source information (I should have had it before, but posted rather rapidly and did not have time).

Comment: Those "reverse knees" below the regular knees are ankles.

Comment: @Tero I've added the links to images that show triple jointed legs, where the satyrs still have a joint at the ankle area (making the middle joint a reverse knee). However, you are correct that in some depictions, there are only the two joints, and so the "reversed knee" is simply an ankle, higher up the leg.

Comment: @ScottS I went through the images and I'm guessing you're mistaking a knuckle for an ankle since it's the first outwardly visible joint off the ground? But trust me, the "reverse knee" is an ankle. To prove my words, here're a couple diagrams to illustrate the internal anatomy of the legs: https://i1.wp.com/www.crittersquad.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Evolution_its_nature_its_evidences_and_its_relation_to_religious_thought_1922_14802898753.jpg?ssl=1 https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/f8/11/4bf8116cc63f32a1ab884d27041ea2ed.jpg Everything below the "second knee" is just foot bones.

Comment: @Tero Okay, I'll concede, even though my unscientific viewpoint of the leg still screams that [this rendition](https://www.deviantart.com/shadowglove/art/Anatomy-of-The-Satyr-84257502) identifying that last joint as where the "heel" is would better match to a common person's view, even if scientists have related by name the lower leg bones of ungulates to bones in the human foot. Thanks for the more precise anatomical education!

Comment: @ScottS I mean, if you're standing on your toes your ankle is still an ankle, that's how scientific I think this is. Think of satyrs as basically just hairy-arsed ballerinas with really long feet. :D

Answer (score 3):

[Stirrups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirrup) greatly increase the rider's ability to stay in the saddle and control the mount, increasing the animal's usefulness to humans in areas such as communication, transportation and warfare.

For an unguligrade to be able to use the same concept, you would need some sort of pouch, where the foot could be fully lodged to allow proper balancing.

On the other hand, for a bare back ride, being unguligrade or plantigrade doesn't make big differences, as the foot will hang loose in both cases.

Comment: A lot of stirrups are metal or wood, it would be simple enough to make a stirrup out of this that would anchor a hoof without trapping it.

Answer (score 1):

When a normal - ok, me, so maybe not that normal :-) - human rides a horse, the feet are enclosed in boots.  The front part of the boot goes in the stirrup, with most of the weight* being carried on the ball of the foot.  This isn't much different from the hoof shown in the unguligrade link.  At most, a minor redesign of the stirrup would be needed.

*Depending on what you're doing, various amounts of your weight are carried by your seat, inner thighs, or feet in stirrups.